# Multiple graphs into one, with value labels

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have plotted to separate graphs into 1. I want to maximize  `z=abs(1+s+(alpha_2)*s.^2+(alpha_1)*(alpha_2)*s.^3)` by trial and error, so the other graphs can be fit inside as big as possible.  So I wanna do two for loops that changes the value for alpha_1 and alpha_2. for example

```
for alpha_1=1:0.5:2
   for alpha_2=1:0.5:2 

    z=abs(1+s+(alpha_2)*s.^2+(alpha_1)*(alpha_2)*s.^3);
    [C,h] = contour(x,y,z,[1 1]);

   end do
end do
```

So the graph would plot 9 different graphs. Is it possible to get these 9 graphs into on figure and say what value of alpha_1 and alpha_2 every graph has?

Orignal program:

```
clear all
close all

alpha_1=0;
alpha_2=0;


theta = 2*pi 
clear t w;
t = 0: theta/100: theta;


w=-1/6*(3-4*cos(t)+cos(2*t)+1i*(8*sin(t)-sin(2*t)));

figure(1)


plot(w,'r')
hold on
%axis( [-10,10, -10,10] )
axis square; grid on

%Contour plot

[x,y] = meshgrid(-2.5 : 0.02:2.5, -2.5 : 0.02: 2.5);
s = x + 1i*y;

z=abs(1+s+(alpha_2)*s.^2+(alpha_1)*(alpha_2)*s.^3);


[C,h] = contour(x,y,z,[1 1]);
clabel(C,h)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html). Maybe something like this:

```
figure;
alpha_1=1:0.5:2;
alpha_2=1:0.5:2;
for id1=1:length(alpha_1)
    for id2=1:length(alpha_2)

        z=abs(1+s+(alpha_2(id2))*s.^2+(alpha_1(id1))*(alpha_2(id2))*s.^3);
        subplot(length(alpha_1),length(alpha_2),id2+(id1-1)*length(alpha_2));
        contour(x,y,z,[1 1]);
        title(['\alpha_1 = ' num2str(alpha_1(id1)) ', \alpha_2 = ' num2str(alpha_2(id2))])

    end
end
```

Comment: Hmmm, they all end up with the same shape.

Comment: I can not comment on the smoothness of the function based on the variable. Maybe try with vastly different alpha1 and alpha2. Also double check are they all on the same scale, maybe you are not comparing like for like.

Comment: @ursmooth Did this answer you question, if it did let us mark as so, otherwise please let me know if the answer can be improved.